# How to make an html dropdown list appear as a roller menu all the time in an ios webapp?

Tags: html, ios, cordova, mobile-website, mobile-application

I'm making a webapp for iOS.

When I make a dropdown list with the  element, it appears as a normal dropdown list until the user actually clicks it, at which time the iOS-style roller menu slides up into view for the user to make a selection.

Is there a way to make that roller menu stay in sight constantly, as the default visible element regardless of whether the user has manipulated it?

The user would just roll it to the value they want, then click a separate continue button, and the roller would stay in view all the while until the page was left.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **perhaps** put focus on the list at the `onload` event, but the menu would lose focus (and disappear) the moment the user would tap elsewhere (ie: another button).

You can't tell Mobile Safari to keep tracking/displaying the drop down any more than you can tell other (desktop) browsers to always display drop menus (as menu, not as lists).

**Edit (for PhoneGap)**
A [quick look at PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/start) makes me believe it simply bundles an UIWebView with a few custom [javascript hooks](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) to API you wouldn't normally have (i.e.: contacts, etc.) from a pure website.  But it's still very much so a "webapp" since UIWebView (on iOS) would be what's rendering it.  So it's still very much a web application and you still have the same constraints (in UI) as a website.

Comment: Hmm, I may have mislabeled my question and misrepresented my program. While it is technically written as a webapp, I'm using PhoneGap so that it is transformed to a native app. The browser does not come into play.

Comment: @Aero, Extended answer to touch on PhoneGap.